# Please explain the following graphs that describe a quantum mechanical harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

Graphs such as the above keep coming up when talking about harmonic oscillators in a quantum mechanical sense. However, I simply cannot make sense of them. What does each line represent why are they waves and what is the parabola? Also, I see sometimes graphs such as:[image]

These seem to follow on from the initial graph. It's something to do with the recovery of classical behavior but I don't understand the first graph so stand no chance of getting the second ones at high n - perhaps you could explain the relation between the first and second graph please? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The parabola is the potential $V(x)$ of the oscillator.

The drawn functions - "waves" - are the energy-wise lowest-lying solutions of the Schrödinger equation with $H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)$, which are numbered by $n$, starting with the lowest energy at $n=1$.

The other graphs show you that, as $n$ increases, the period of oscillation in the quantum probability gets smaller and smaller, making it graphically plausible that classical behaviour is recovered as $n\to\infty$, as required by the [correspondence principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle).

Answer (score 1):

The confusion with this type of graph often originates from the nature of the y-axis. Here, it is doing two jobs at once. For the parabola describing the potential well and the baselines for the eigenstates $\Psi_n$ it is an energy axis. So we can see the potential energy of a particle in the well rises as one moves away from the origin, and higher order states (increasing $n$ in $\Psi_n$) have increased energy. But it is also (implicitly) showing the amplitude of the wavefunction for each state. So, for example, the undulating blue line which is labelled $\Psi_3$ is not showing the change of energy of $\Psi_3$ as a function of position, but rather the amplitude of the wavefunction as a function of position.

So it is many graphs in one - one of energy *vs* position for the parabola and five of amplitude *vs* position for the wave functions. The wavefunction graphs are drawn on the potential energy graph at vertical positions corresponding to the energy of that state.

Comment: And having written that out, I can see why it's confusing!